# xsl sorting weird behavior

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I am facing a weird behavior while trying to sort my input XML:

My XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<!--  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>  -->

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="name">
     <xsl:sort select="@rank" data-type="number"/>   
     <xsl:sort collation = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/collation/codepoint"/>    
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="name">
  <name rank="{@rank}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="text()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="name">
    <xsl:sort select="@rank" data-type="number"/>    
    <xsl:sort collation = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/collation/codepoint" />    
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </name>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When my input XML is of the form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Sources>
<name rank="">Continents / Regions (energy)</name>
<name rank="">Continents / Regions</name>
</Sources>
```

it is sorted correctly as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Sources>
    <name rank="">Continents / Regions</name>
    <name rank="">Continents / Regions (energy)</name>    
    </Sources>
```

However, when the input is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Sources>
<name rank="">Continents / Regions (energy)
  <name rank="">ABC</name>
</name>
<name rank="">Continents / Regions
  <name rank="">ABC</name>
</name>
</Sources>
```

the output is incorrect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Sources>
<name rank="">Continents / Regions (energy)
  <name rank="">ABC</name>
</name>
<name rank="">Continents / Regions
  <name rank="">ABC</name>
</name>
</Sources>
```

Would appreciate it if someone could give me pointers as to what i should be looking at. Thanks in advance!

Edit: The XSLT processor being used is Saxon HE 9.4 . This is my Java code.

```
tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance("net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl",null);

Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(RCSTestDriver.TestDataPath + "/transform.xslt"));
```

Comment: Consider to show us the result you want for the input posted. What is the `<xsl:sort select="@rank" data-type="number"/> ` good for? I don't see any `rank` attributes in the posted samples. And which XSLT (2.0?) processor do you use? Have you tried a different one to compare the output?

Comment: It assumes that the rank is blank, if it is not present, I tried using the XAlan processor as well, but face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

When I try to reproduce the problem with the input document being

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Sources>
<name>Continents / Regions (energy)
  <name>ABC</name>
</name>
<name>Continents / Regions
  <name>ABC</name>
</name>
</Sources>
```

the stylesheet as posted and the XSLT 2.0 processor Saxon 9.4 HE run from the command line I can't reproduce it, instead I get the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Sources>
   <name rank="">Continents / Regions

<name rank="">ABC</name>
   </name>
   <name rank="">Continents / Regions (energy)

<name rank="">ABC</name>
   </name>
</Sources>
```

Comment: this is weird. I tried running it from the command line as well, but I was able to reproduce it, both with JRE 6 and 7. this is the command that i used, `java -jar C:\QA\Selenium Tutorial\lib\saxon9he
.jar TestXML.xml transform.xslt -0:output.xml`

Answer (score 0):

It rather depends how much whitespace there is (which is hard to tell from your posting). But the string value "Continents / Regions ABC" should certainly precede "Continents / Regions (energy) ABC", because "(" precedes "A". Perhaps you overlooked that "ABC" is part of your sort key?